# ios if statement not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement

i just want to ask why my "IF" statement is not working now, earlier its working fine, i just made an version for iPad then after that its not working anymore. this is my if statements.

```
- (void)textFieldDidChanges{

    if ([self.feet1.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
        self.feet1.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];


    if([self.feet2.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
        self.feet2.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    if([self.feet3.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
        self.feet3.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    if([self.feet4.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
        self.feet4.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    if([self.feet5.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
        self.feet5.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    if([self.feet6.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
        self.feet6.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    if([self.feet7.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
        self.feet7.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    if([self.feet8.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
        self.feet8.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    if([self.feet9.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
        self.feet9.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    if([self.feet10.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
        self.feet10.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    if([self.feet11.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
        self.feet11.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    if([self.feet12.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
        self.feet12.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    if([self.feet13.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
        self.feet13.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    if([self.feet14.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
        self.feet14.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    if([self.feet15.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
        self.feet15.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    if([self.feet15.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
        self.feet15.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    if([self.feet16.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
        self.feet16.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    if([self.feet17.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
        self.feet17.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    if([self.feet18.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
        self.feet18.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    if([self.feet19.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
        self.feet19.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    if([self.feet20.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
        self.feet20.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    if([self.feet21.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
        self.feet21.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    if([self.feet22.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
        self.feet22.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    if([self.feet23.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
        self.feet23.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    if([self.feet24.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
        self.feet24.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    if([self.feet25.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
        self.feet25.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    if([self.feet26.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
        self.feet26.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    if([self.feet27.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
        self.feet27.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    if([self.feet28.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
        self.feet28.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    if([self.feet29.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
        self.feet29.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    if([self.feet30.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
        self.feet30.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    if([self.feet31.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
        self.feet31.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    if([self.feet32.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
        self.feet32.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    if([self.feet33.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
        self.feet33.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    if([self.feet34.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
        self.feet34.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    if([self.feet35.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
        self.feet35.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    if([self.feet36.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
        self.feet36.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    if([self.feet37.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
        self.feet37.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    if([self.feet38.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
        self.feet38.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    if([self.feet39.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
        self.feet39.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    if([self.feet40.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
        self.feet40.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    if([self.feet41.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
        self.feet41.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    if([self.feet42.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
        self.feet42.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    if([self.feet43.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
        self.feet43.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    if([self.feet44.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
        self.feet44.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    if([self.feet45.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
        self.feet45.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    if([self.feet46.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
        self.feet46.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    if([self.feet47.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
        self.feet47.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    if([self.feet48.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
        self.feet48.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    if([self.feet49.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
        self.feet49.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    if([self.feet50.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
        self.feet50.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];



    //HIDDEN YES

    if ([self.feet1.text length] == 0)
        self.feet1.hidden = YES;


    if([self.feet2.text length] == 0)
        self.feet2.hidden = YES;

    if([self.feet3.text length] == 0)
        self.feet3.hidden = YES;

    if([self.feet4.text length] == 0)
        self.feet4.hidden = YES;

    if([self.feet5.text length] == 0)
        self.feet5.hidden = YES;

    if([self.feet6.text length] == 0)
        self.feet6.hidden = YES;

    if([self.feet7.text length] == 0)
        self.feet7.hidden = YES;

    if([self.feet8.text length] == 0)
        self.feet8.hidden = YES;

    if([self.feet9.text length] == 0)
        self.feet9.hidden = YES;

    if([self.feet10.text length] == 0)
        self.feet10.hidden = YES;

    if([self.feet11.text length] == 0)
        self.feet11.hidden = YES;

    if([self.feet12.text length] == 0)
        self.feet12.hidden = YES;

    if([self.feet13.text length] == 0)
        self.feet13.hidden = YES;

    if([self.feet14.text length] == 0)
        self.feet14.hidden = YES;

    if([self.feet15.text length] == 0)
        self.feet15.hidden = YES;

    if([self.feet15.text length] == 0)
        self.feet15.hidden = YES;

    if([self.feet16.text length] == 0)
        self.feet16.hidden = YES;

    if([self.feet17.text length] == 0)
        self.feet17.hidden = YES;

    if([self.feet18.text length] == 0)
        self.feet18.hidden = YES;

    if([self.feet19.text length] == 0)
        self.feet19.hidden = YES;

    if([self.feet20.text length] == 0)
        self.feet20.hidden = YES;

    if([self.feet21.text length] == 0)
        self.feet21.hidden = YES;

    if([self.feet22.text length] == 0)
        self.feet22.hidden = YES;

    if([self.feet23.text length] == 0)
        self.feet23.hidden = YES;

    if([self.feet24.text length] == 0)
        self.feet24.hidden = YES;

    if([self.feet25.text length] == 0)
        self.feet25.hidden = YES;

    if([self.feet26.text length] == 0)
        self.feet26.hidden = YES;

    if([self.feet27.text length] == 0)
        self.feet27.hidden = YES;

    if([self.feet28.text length] == 0)
        self.feet28.hidden = YES;

    if([self.feet29.text length] == 0)
        self.feet29.hidden = YES;

    if([self.feet30.text length] == 0)
        self.feet30.hidden = YES;

    if([self.feet31.text length] == 0)
        self.feet31.hidden = YES;

    if([self.feet32.text length] == 0)
        self.feet32.hidden = YES;

    if([self.feet33.text length] == 0)
        self.feet33.hidden = YES;

    if([self.feet34.text length] == 0)
        self.feet34.hidden = YES;

    if([self.feet35.text length] == 0)
        self.feet35.hidden = YES;

    if([self.feet36.text length] == 0)
        self.feet36.hidden = YES;

    if([self.feet37.text length] == 0)
        self.feet37.hidden = YES;

    if([self.feet38.text length] == 0)
        self.feet38.hidden = YES;

    if([self.feet39.text length] == 0)
        self.feet39.hidden = YES;

    if([self.feet40.text length] == 0)
        self.feet40.hidden = YES;

    if([self.feet41.text length] == 0)
        self.feet41.hidden = YES;

    if([self.feet42.text length] == 0)
        self.feet42.hidden = YES;

    if([self.feet43.text length] == 0)
        self.feet43.hidden = YES;

    if([self.feet44.text length] == 0)
        self.feet44.hidden = YES;

    if([self.feet45.text length] == 0)
        self.feet45.hidden = YES;

    if([self.feet46.text length] == 0)
        self.feet46.hidden = YES;

    if([self.feet47.text length] == 0)
        self.feet47.hidden = YES;

    if([self.feet48.text length] == 0)
        self.feet48.hidden = YES;

    if([self.feet49.text length] == 0)
        self.feet49.hidden = YES;

    if([self.feet50.text length] == 0)
        self.feet50.hidden = YES;



}
```

i just put some of it because theres a characters limit.. this is the labels. "feet1 - feet50(as shows above),inches1 - inches50,basket1 - basket50 and fruits1 - fruits50.. as you can see on the if statement i want all that labels to have gray background if the text is 0 and i want it hidden of no text. BTW i use this timer to update it every second so there's no problem with updating in realtime..

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(textFieldDidChanges)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];
```

what do you think seems to be the problem here? thanks for all your helps!

EDIT: i forgot to include my main problem this is it.

the problem is the statement is working at first load of the app, but if the assigned labels changes the text i mean if the lable is not "0" anymore it stays gray. and all the hidden labels at first stays hidden even if i knew that it has a text on the label.

Comment: You never said what the problem is.

Comment: the IF statement is not working that is his problem

Comment: Better use an array where you put all this labels than all this code...

Comment: By the time you copied and pasted 5 times were you not thinking: 'surely I'm doing something wrong here...' ?

Comment: which one? you have thousands

Comment: oh sorry, i was too excited. lol ,the problem is the statement is working at first load of the app, but if the assigned labels changes the text i mean if the lable is not "0" anymore it stays gray. and all the hidden labels at first stays hidden even if i knew that it has a text on the label.

Comment: @A'saDickens Yes, the if statement isn not working. But *how* is it not working? What is it doing instead of the expected behavior?

Comment: Use if... else if ... ladder, or for optimized coding use switch conditions

Comment: @jcesar all of the assigned labels.

Comment: @Larme can you provide some array samples?

Comment: @Manimaran, this is not the case of if-elseif.

Comment: i also tried to test just 1 single label with that if statement. but i got the same thing. it doesn't change.

Comment: Add breakpoints on start of this method. Use if-elsif for proper code structure. Debugging the code will let know better understanding over the code execution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for (UILabel *aLabel in yourArrayOfLabels)
{
    [self modifyAppearnceOfLabel:aLabel];
}

-(void)modifyAppearanceOfLabel:(UILabel*)aLabel
{
    if ([[aLabel text] length] == 0)
        [aLabel setHidden:YES];
    else
        [aLabel setHidden:FALSE];

    if ([[aLabelText text] isEqualToString:@"0"])
        [[aLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGray]];
    else
        [[aLabel setBackgroundColor:theColorYouWant]];
}
```

Comment: I'll add that if you really can't do better than declare theses 50 labels manually, you can construct `yourArrayOfLabels` this way:
`NSMutableArray *yourArrayOfLabels = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i <= 50; i ++){NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"feet%d", i]; [yourArrayOfLabels addObject:[self valueForKey:key]];}`

Answer (score 6):

From the code that you have shown, you are only ever setting to hidden and grey. You never set to visible or another colour. That's your 'problem'.

But your code is extremely inefficient. And using a timer seems like entirely the wrong approach based on your description.

You should have all of these text fields in an array. You should be the delegate of the text fields and responding specifically to changes in each one.

Also, I guess you have a million IBOutlets. It would be better to create these text fields in code and use an algorithm to lay them out (rather than assign all the outlets into an array). So, as you iterate over the required number of text fields you increment a counter and use that counter to calculate the `frame.origin` that the text field should be at, create the text field, add a delegate, add as a subview, add to the array.

Though, by the time you have added your controller as a delegate you might not need an array at all...

Comment: Dude, the amount of horrible code in the universe in limitless. If you lose sleep over bad code you might as well pack it in now. "Illegitimi non carborundum". This guy is obviously a beginner.

Comment: @DuncanC, true indeed and calming words. I like the 'latin', hadn't seen that before.

Answer (score 0):

You may use UITextField Delegate

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{

    NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    if(textField == self.feet1)
    {
      if([string isEqualToString:@"0"])
      {
        //Do something 
        textField..backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
      }
    }
    else if(textField == self.feet2)
    {
      if([string isEqualToString:@"0"])
      {
        //Do something 
        textField..backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
      }
    }
    .
    .
    .
    .


}


It is better to add all textField objects in a NSMutableArray and update the array contents to decrease number of lines of code like 

for(NSInteger index = 0; index< 15; index++)
{
    UITextField *txt = [array objectAtIndex:i];
    //change the properties you want.
    txt.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
}
```